# Is user46646 a real user or just an aggregate of anonymous users?

Tags: discussion

Just came across this profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/46646/user46646?tab=profile. It has a lot of reputation, no answers, and some very poor questions.

Is this a real user?

Comment: 89% of the posts are in python, i'd assume it's a real user that gained most of it's rep over a long period of time due to incremental votes on popular questions. In other words, this user got lucky and asked simple questions before anyone else did for a popular language.

Comment: When they went inactive, they had less than 5k reputation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a perfect example on living off the long tail of reputation.  They have several questions that has given them the majority of their reputation.

See:

- [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)
- [How to get current time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)
- [How can I make a time delay in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510348/how-can-i-make-a-time-delay-in-python)
- [How to determine the variable type in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-the-variable-type-in-python)
- [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)
- [Why doesn't Python have a switch statement? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374239/why-doesnt-python-have-a-switch-statement)

These have been around for years and the user consitently gets reputation from them.

Comment: `"This looks like a perfect example on living off the long tail of reputation."` -- If only this were so. I found my rep can occasionally get me a T-shirt, but that's it. No beer, no pizza, nothing I can live off of.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It's called bartering.  You trade that precious SO T-shirt or mug to someone with rep envy for a pizza ;)